# Get rid of the name tab on top bar

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm making a responsive top bar when the screen is minimized to 700px or less the top bar would hide its other tabs, all of the other tabs are successful except for one. Here is the picture

**When not minimized**
[image]

**My Problem (when minimized)**

[image]

**When the 3 bars are clicked(when minimized)**

[image]

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
 function myFunction() {
      var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
      if (x.className === "navbar") {
        x.className += " responsive";
      } else {
        x.className = "navbar";
      }
    }
```

**CSS:**

```
  .icon {
      display: none;
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
      .navbar a:not(:first-child),
      .dropdown .dropbtn,
      .dropdowna .dropalvin,
      .one {
        display: none;
      }
      .navbar a.icon {
        float: right;
        display: block;
      }
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
      .navbar.responsive {
        position: relative;
      }
      .navbar.responsive .icon {
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
      }
      .navbar.responsive a {
        float: none;
        display: block;
        text-align: left;
      }
      .navbar.responsive .dropdown,
      .dropdowna {
        float: none;
      }
      .navbar.responsive .dropdown-content,
      .dropdown-contents {
        position: relative;
      }
      .navbar.responsive .dropdown .dropbtn,
      .dropdowna .dropalvin {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: left;
      }
    }

    .navbar {
      overflow: hidden;
      background-color: #ffe602;
    }

    .navbar a {
      float: left;
      font-size: 14px;
      color: black;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 14px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
    }

    .dropdown {
      float: left;
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    .dropdowna {
      float: right;
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    .dropdown .dropbtn,
    .dropdowna .dropalvin {
      font-size: 14px;
      border: none;
      outline: none;
      color: black;
      padding: 14px 16px;
      background-color: inherit;
      font-family: inherit;
      margin: 0;
    }

    .navbar a:hover,
    .dropdown:hover .dropbtn,
    .dropdowna:hover .dropalvin {
      background-color: #9E8F03;
    }

    .dropdown-content {
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
      background-color: #f9f9f9;
      width: 214px;
      box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
      z-index: 1;
    }

    .dropdown-contents {
      background-color: #f9f9f9;
      box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
      z-index: 1;
    }

    .dropdown-content a,
    .dropdown-contents a {
      float: none;
      color: black;
      padding: 12px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: block;
      text-align: left;
    }

    .dropdown-content a:hover,
    .dropdown-contents a:hover {
      background-color: #151b54;
      color: white;
    }

    .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content,
    .dropdowna:hover .dropdown-contents {
      display: block;
    }
```

**HTML:**

```
 <div class="navbar" id="myTopnav">
      <a href="homepage.php">HOME</a>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn">STUDENT MANAGEMENT
          <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="addrequirements.php">ADD REQUIREMENTS</a>
          <a href="add students.php">ADD STUDENTS</a>
        </div>
      </div>

      <a href="SEARCH STUDENTS.php">SEARCH STUDENT</a></span>
      <a href="classlist.php">CLASS LIST COLLEGE</a></span>
      <a href="classlist1.php">CLASS LIST SHS</a><span>
        <a class="one"   id = "se" href="aboutus.php">ABOUT US</a></span>

      <div style="width:auto;" class="dropdowna">
        <button id="h" class="dropalvin"><span><?php echo $_SESSION['Fname']?> <?php echo $_SESSION['Mname']?> <?php echo $_SESSION['Lname']?></span>
          <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
        </button>
        <div style="width:auto;" class="dropdown-contents">
          <a href="loghistory.php">Log History</a>
          <a href="logout.php">Log Out</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:13px;" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
    </div>
```

are there any way to get rid that name? i have tried it to place its class name in @media to to display: none it when the screen is minimized but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

Try to move

```
<button id="h" class="dropalvin"><span><?php echo $_SESSION['Fname']?> <?php echo $_SESSION['Mname']?> <?php echo $_SESSION['Lname']?></span>
          <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
        </button>
```

to navbar and convert it to a:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  if (x.className === "navbar") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "navbar";
  }
}
```

```css
.icon {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .navbar a:not(:first-child),
  .dropdown .dropbtn,
  .dropdowna .dropalvin,
  .one {
    display: none;
  }
  .navbar a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .navbar.responsive {
    position: relative;
  }
  .navbar.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .navbar.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
  .navbar.responsive .dropdown,
  .dropdowna {
    float: none;
  }
  .navbar.responsive .dropdown-content,
  .dropdown-contents {
    position: relative;
  }
  .navbar.responsive .dropdown .dropbtn,
  .dropdowna .dropalvin {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
  }
}

.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #ffe602;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdowna {
  float: right;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn,
.dropdowna .dropalvin {
  font-size: 14px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn,
.dropdowna:hover .dropalvin {
  background-color: #9E8F03;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  width: 214px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-contents {
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a,
.dropdown-contents a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover,
.dropdown-contents a:hover {
  background-color: #151b54;
  color: white;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content,
.dropdowna:hover .dropdown-contents {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar" id="myTopnav">
  <a href="homepage.php">HOME</a>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">STUDENT MANAGEMENT
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="addrequirements.php">ADD REQUIREMENTS</a>
      <a href="add students.php">ADD STUDENTS</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <a href="SEARCH STUDENTS.php">SEARCH STUDENT</a>
  <a href="classlist.php">CLASS LIST COLLEGE</a>
  <a href="classlist1.php">CLASS LIST SHS</a>
  <a class="one"   id = "se" href="aboutus.php">ABOUT US</a>
    <!-- HERE -->
  <a id="h" class="dropalvin"><span>John Doe</span>
    <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
  </a>

  <div style="width:auto;" class="dropdowna">
    <div style="width:auto;" class="dropdown-contents">
      <a href="loghistory.php">Log History</a>
      <a href="logout.php">Log Out</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:13px;" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
</div>
```

Comment: It worked if i remain the <a> tag, but i want the name to be floated at right side (if nit minimized and when the user hover the mouse in the name it would show a dropdown Log History and Log out

Comment: i have to enclosed him with the with the <div class="dropdowna"> to trigger the dropdown, but it just the same problem (my photo when minimized)